# "Digest verification failed" when updating system

Tags: package-management, opensuse, upgrade

When I run `sudo zypper update`:

```
Overall download size: 134.1 MiB. After the operation, additional 5.7 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/?] (y): y
Automatically agreeing with java-1_6_0-sun-devel package license.
Automatically agreeing with java-1_6_0-sun package license.
Automatically agreeing with java-1_6_0-sun-plugin package license.
Retrieving package libbluray0-0+20111019-1.1.x86_64 (1/54), 60.0 KiB (159.0 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libbluray0-0+20111019-1.1.x86_64.rpm [done]
Retrieving package MPlayer-1.0rc4_r34240-2.1.x86_64 (2/54), 17.9 MiB (49.1 MiB unpacked)
Retrieving: MPlayer-1.0rc4_r34240-2.1.x86_64.rpm [done (1.9 MiB/s)]
Retrieving package libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2.x86_64 (3/54), 174.0 KiB (434.0 KiB unpacked)
Retrieving: libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2.x86_64.rpm [done (0 B/s)]
Digest verification failed for libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2.x86_64.rpm. Expected f065534feb71adf943a5e4f86c2bdb4fd930ee36b8ca8b672062f65510f66584, found d9b8e0ac120e1870d6988aa1157190bfd39225fe24aa24e3ab79a60efd3aa6ae. Continue? [yes/no] (no): yes
Package libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2 seems to be corrupted during transfer. Do you want to retry retrieval?
Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a): i
```

I haven't changed anything in my repos recently so I don't know why curl isn't cooperating. What does this error mean? And where does the problem lie?

**SOLVED**

I ended up having to run `sudo zypper refresh` before re-trying my update. Thanks to *rozcietrzewiacz* for hinting to it.

Comment: I understand that you are using openSUSE - right? Please don't forget to mention the distribution in the future.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: My bad, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might origin from various places. What it means? Just as the message says: a downloaded file does not match its recorded checksum. Re-fetch the file and it should be OK (just press <kbd>r</kbd> to retry). Otherwise report it as a bug or try syncing/updating a bit later.

Comment: It's been happening for 3 days, and I've 'retried' a couple times now. Is this just a waiting game?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the downloaded file `libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2.x86_64.rpm` before attempting an update?

Comment: Also, I can see that "`zypper`" has a **`refresh`** command. Did you use it recently, with all your repositories?

Comment: How would I go about removing the downloaded file? (something along the lines of `rpm -e libcurl4-7.22.0-59.2.x86_64.rpm` ?). And no, I haven't refreshed recently.

Comment: You decide: either look into zypper/openSUSE documentation to find out where such downloads are stored *or* use a tool like `find` or `locate` (the last needs indexing to be preformed via `updatedb` first).

Comment: But the most important thing you should try **first** is refreshing the repositories! The checksum might have been incorrectly recorded when you last did this.